# Openerp Product category domain filter

Tags: python, xml, odoo, openerp-7

I have multiple categories of products. On one form, I want to select product of type1 category, and on other, product of type2 category. My code is:

```
<field name="product_id" domain="[(product_id.categ_id.name, '=', 'type1')]"></field>
```

But when I go to selection it says:

```
ValueError: Invalid field 'product_id.categ_id.name' in leaf "<osv.ExtendedLeaf: ('product_id.categ_id.name', '=', 'Tools') on product_product (ctx: )>"
```

Comment: why you use product_id.product_id.name instead of using categ_id in domain ?

Comment: @senthilnathang Thank you, Just figured it out. It should be  ('categ_id.name','=','type1')

Comment: then in write it as an  answer